# Help with general Leibniz rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having some trouble using Leibniz's theorem. I understand using the theorem to get the expressions for the LHS. In 5.a) why is a -1 multiplied to the RHS?
Similarly on the RHS for part c) why is it multiplied by -n^2?

[5.a) and c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdlq0.png)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${\frac  {d(sinx)}{dx}}=cosx$  followed by which  ${\frac  {d(cosx)}{dx}}=-sinx$

${\frac  {d(acosnx +bsinnx)}{dx}}=n(asinnx-bcosnx)$ followed by which

${\frac  {d(n(asinnx-bcosnx))}{dx}}=-n^2(acosnx +bsinnx)$

Comment: Ahh I understand now ty!!

Comment: no problem! please upvote if  this answer helped you

Comment: I have tried but it says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: its alright then